# json_encode no me retorna nada

Tags: php, postman

tengo un problema con este código. Al mandar datos con postman no me retorna nada, solo un espacio en blanco.

Les anexo el código aquí, si pudiera alguien ayudarme que necesito esto para conectar por medio de volley con android.

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","_igo_test");

    if(isset($_POST["email"]) && ($_POST["celular"]) && ($_POST["password"])){
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $celular = $_POST["celular"]; 
    $pass = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT nombre, apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,
    celular, email FROM _clientes_taxis WHERE email = ? OR
    celular = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $email,$celular,$pass);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $nombre, $a_paterno, $a_materno, $cel, $correo);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

      while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
         $response['success'] = true;
         $response['nombre'] = $nombre;
         $response['apellido_paterno'] = $a_paterno;
         $response['apellido_materno'] = $a_materno;
         $response['celular'] =  $cel;
         $response['email'] = $correo;
      }
      print_r($response);
      echo json_encode($response);
   }      
?>
```

Comment: hazle un print_r($response); y mira si imprime, y añadele la cabecera header('Content-type: application/json'); antes de hacer echo

Comment: y el `print_r($response);` devuelve algo?

Comment: @MarioGonzalesFlores, me sigue sin retornar nada

Comment: @Bryro, no retorna nada :'(

Comment: sino retorna nada el problema esta en tu consulta, verifica que arroja valores o cambia a una que si lo haga e imprime tus variables post
echo $nombre;

Comment: intentanta agrupando la query ejemplo: `SELECT nombre, apellido_paterno,apellido_materno, celular, email FROM _clientes_taxis WHERE (email = ? OR celular = ? ) AND password = ?` [ejemplo correcto](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64413e/13)

Comment: Haría falta ver el formulario para saber si los parámetros son correctos. Además te faltan un par de `isset` en la comprobación del principio, lo cual puede hacer que ocurra un error y no se ejecute el script completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bienvenido. Intenta modificar tu codigo y agrega una validación antes de hacer el procesamiento de tu información, agrega los headers y quita el print antes del echo para devolver el json.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
     try {
        if ((!isset($_POST["email"]) or !isset($_POST["password"])) or
            (!strlen($_POST["email"]) > 0 or !strlen($_POST["password"] > 0))) {
            $response = ["success" => false, "message" => "parámetros inválidos"];
            echo json_encode($response);
            return;
        }

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "_igo_test");

        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $celular = $_POST["celular"];
        $pass = $_POST["password"];

        $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT nombre, apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,
celular, email FROM _clientes_taxis WHERE email = ? OR
celular = ? AND password = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $email, $celular, $pass);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $nombre, $a_paterno, $a_materno, $cel, $correo);

        $response = array();
        $response["success"] = false;

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
            $row = [];
            $row['nombre'] = $nombre;
            $row['apellido_paterno'] = $a_paterno;
            $row['apellido_materno'] = $a_materno;
            $row['celular'] = $cel;
            $row['email'] = $correo;

            $response[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $response = ["success" => false, "message" => "Exception:: " . $e->getMessage()];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Avisame si te sirve, saludos!

Comment: ** Me esta tirando esto ** 
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "parámetros inválidos"
}

Comment: los parámetros que esperas no estan llegando. Checa que te devuelve al hacer un var_dump($_POST); die(); echo "<pre>"; al inicio de tu script; Debes de ver email y password sino entonces los estas enviando incorrectamente ya sea desde otro script o desde algun cliente como postman o desde frontend.

Comment: array(2) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(20) "david_ep@hotmail.com"
  ["password"]=>
  string(32) "9b904ab4dfbc00d524f120d7918568ac"
}

esto es lo que me devuelve, pero nada de la consulta sql

Comment: y si lo mando raw como JSON solo aparece {}

Comment: ok la consulta es la que no te retorna datos, creo esta mal el query intenta agrupar correo y celular moficalo así. SELECT nombre, apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,
celular, email FROM _clientes_taxis WHERE (email = ? OR
celular = ?) AND password = ?

Comment: me sigue regresando lo mismo :'(

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, comenta la línea mysqli_stmt_bind_result y ve si te funciona.

Comment: sigue dando lo mismo bro

Comment: Estás usando postman con el verbo POST y añadiendo los parámetros en la pestaña de BODY?

Comment: es correcto @Jakala

Comment: al parecer habia una "t" de más en strlen pero ahora me regresa un 
{"success": false} si no pongo var_dump($_POST); die(); echo "<pre>"
y al ponerlo me regresa los datos que mando por POST pero no la consulta

Comment: ya esta resuelto, era eso de la "t" de más y que en mi consulta se me escapo una "s", muchisimas gracias